# Manual 'Add to Cart' link

Tags: drupal-6, ubercart

Is there a way in Drupal to output an 'Add to Cart' link in static content? Like a block? Once clicked, throws 1 in the cart, and takes you to /cart?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Added 'Buy It Now' button from the Product group in a view. Could not do this in static block content.